# Помогите с написанием легкой программы в СИ

Tags: c

Цель: определение длины той части строки s, которая не содержит символы из строки s1

Мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    char S[256], S1[256];
    int n, k, g;
    k = 0;
    printf_s("Введите строку S:");
    gets_s(S);
    printf_s("Введите строку S1:");
    gets_s(S1);
    for (int j = 0, i = 0; j < strlen(S1), i < strlen(S); i++, j++) {
        if (S[i] != S1[j]) {
            n = 0;
            n = n + 1;
            if (strlen(S) != strlen(S1)) {
                k = abs(char(strlen(S) - strlen(S1)));
            }
        }
    }
        g = n + k;
        printf("%d\n", strlen(S));
        printf("%d\n", strlen(S1));
        printf("%d\n", g);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: [strcspn](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strspn) вам в помощь

Answer (score -1):

```
int flag = 0;
for (int i=0; i<strlen(S); i++) {
    for (int j=0; i<strlen(S1); j++) {
       if (S[i] == S1[j]) {
          flag = 1;
          break;
       }
    }
    if (flag == 0)
        prinf("%c", S[i]);
    else
        break;
}
printf("\n");
```